# Adding "id" properties where there are navigation properties (EF)

Tags: entity-framework

If I have a navigation property (ie: virtual), for example:
`public virtual User Author { get; set; }`

And I want to have also the id of that User, ie:
`public int AuthorId { get; set; }`

How can I tell EF that this "AuthorId" must be related to the Author property?

I don't like the idea of this being automatic (EF magically deducing this).
Because one could have multiple references to the same table:

```
public virtual User Author { get; set; }
public int AuthorId { get; set; }
public virtual User Receiver { get; set; }
public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entity framework will assume that the AuthorID is the FK of the Author class.  See [this blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx) for the details.

You could also explicitly tell EF, by using data annotations:

```
[ForeignKey("Author")]
public int AuthorId {get;set;}
```

or by using fluent mappings:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourClass>().HasRequired(p => p.Author)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorId);
```

Comment: In: ForeignKey("X"), X is a class identifier or a property identifier?

Comment: it is the property identifier, in your example, you could have ForeignKey("Author") and ForeignKey("Reciever")